# How to include and use Golden Layout on Angular 2 using ng2-admin theme and folder structure

Tags: angular, typescript, golden-layout

I'm new to Angular 2 and including Golden Layout on the Dashboard of a project has been a hassle. I'm using ng2-admin theme and would not like to change the folder structure.

http://akveo.com/ng2-admin/#/pages/dashboard

How can I accomplish this task ?

A working demo or plunker would be much appreciated.